# Save Data (Keep text in textfields on next launch)

Tags: objective-c, persistent-storage

I have a bunch of text fields where the user types in their data. There is 6 text fields for each day (excl. Sat, Sun) and I need the data (string text) in the textfields to be saved so that they are their on next launch.

How would I go about doing this, thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827840/ios-persistent-storage-framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_sundayTextField.text ForKey:@"Sunday"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // Writes modifications to disk thus making your data persistent between launches
```

And when your text fields are created :

```
_sundayTextField = (NSString*)[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Sunday"];
```

Do this for the other days as well and make sure the object stored in the user defaults dictionary is not `null` (if so just leave the text field empty or use an initial value).

`NSUserDefaults` is easy to use and is persistent between launches. 
For more complex data [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is preferred.

Comment: After setting the object don't forget to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: @Flexicoder of course, thanks for the remark I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of choices

1. `NSUserDefaults` - [How to save data with NSUserDefaults using data from NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396365/how-to-save-data-with-nsuserdefaults-using-data-from-nsmutablearray)
2. Write the data to a plist and reload it - [iPhone read/write .plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335475/iphone-read-write-plist-file)
3. CoreData - http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Really depends what you are hoping to achieve with the data you are storing